# update from another table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have two tables. I need to bring data from one table to another based on `where` clause.

```sql
UPDATE cats_new c
SET c.INFO_REQ = (select min(w.tRANSITION_DATE) from CATS_new_history w)
where  w.CANDIDATEID = c.CANDIDATE_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

This is close, but you have to move your WHERE condition into the subquery so that the subquery is "correlated":

```
UPDATE cats_new c
SET c.INFO_REQ = 
  (
     SELECT min(w.tRANSITION_DATE) 
     FROM CATS_new_history w
     WHERE w.CANDIDATEID = c.CANDIDATE_ID
  )
```

You can see more examples [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php). Specifically the first example labelled "Example - Update table with data from another table"

Answer (score 3):

Two options I can think of; one follows JNevill's suggestion with another piece of advice: include `where` clause to restrict rows which will be updated, because - if there's no match in subquery - you'll update those rows' values to `NULL`. That's what `EXISTS` part of query handles:

```
update cats_new c set
  c.info_req = (select min(w.transition_date)
                from cats_new_history w
                where w.candidateid = c.candidate_id
               )
  where exists (select null
                from cats_new_history a
                where a.candidateid = c.candidate_id
               );
```

---

Another option is `merge`; although it is usually used to "replace" upsert operation (`update` AND `insert`), no problem if you use it only for one of those - `update` in this case; its `on` clause handles which rows will be affected:

```
merge into cats_new c
  using (select w.candidateid, 
                min(w.transition_date) transition_date
         from cats_new_history w
         group by w.candidateid
        ) x
  on (c.candidate_id = x.candidateid)
when matched then update set
  c.info_req = x.transition_date;
```